# Enabling Group description field for webforms

Tags: webform-civicrm, groups, gdpr

The group description field is visible when using a profile for mailing sign ups.

Does anyone know of a way of including these in a civi enabled webform?

Ta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drupal Webform (core) module does not natively support descriptions of individual checkboxes or select options, so there isn't a built-in way to achieve this. A workaround would be to type the description in yourself by changing "Live Options" to "Static Options" and placing the description in parentheses after the title.

Comment: Thanks Coleman.

I've added descriptions in a mark up field on the form. Amending the static options label doesn't play well with all page layouts.